# Haskell Question on pattern matching

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a list and returns true if it is in sorted order and false if not:

So far what I have is:

```
myordered [] = True
myordered [x] = True
myordered list1
 | (head list1) <= (head (tail list1)) = myordered(tail list1)
 | otherwise                           = False
```

Based on our assignment, all head and tail operations should be written down as "x:xs" type syntax.

the translation I come up with for the section with a guard is:

```
myordered y:x:xs
 | (y) <= (x) = myordered(xs)
 | otherwise  = False
```

Essentially this question boils down to:
How do you express the (head (tail list1)) in "x:xs" type syntax?

Cheers,
-Zigu

Answer (score 9):

Your pattern is almost correct, you just need to surround it with parentheses:

```
myordered (y:x:xs)
```

Also note that there's no need to surround `y` and `x` with parentheses in `y <= x`.

Also there's a semantic mistake in your second version:

`myordered(xs)` here `xs` refers to the tail of tail, but you want the whole tail, so you should do `myordered (x:xs)` or alternatively:

```
myordered (y:xs@(x:_))
 | y <= x = myordered xs
 | otherwise  = False
```

Which says: `xs` is the tail of that list, `x` is the head of that tail, and `_` (which is ignored) is the tail of the tail.

Comment: Since this is homework, reconstructing the tail may be easier to understand: myordered (y:x:xs) | y <= x = myordered (x:xs).

Comment: @yatima: Well, that was the first option I gave.

Answer (score 4):

How about another way to do this with the help of `zipWith` function available in `Data.List`

```
 myordered xs= and $ zipWith (<=) xs (tail xs)
```

`zipWith` function takes two list and apply a function. Here it will return an array of boolean according to the condition .
`and` takes a list of boolean values and returns True only if all the values in the list are True

Comment: This is a beautiful idiomatic solution... that a beginner would not write. I think the teacher would catch on :-P

Comment: I like it.  The only thing I'd change is 'drop 1' instead of 'tail', so that it works on [].

Comment: `zipWith` will handle [] , so tail function inside `zipWith` will work without any exception

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
isordered :: [Int] →  Bool
isordered [] = True
isordered xs = foldl (&&) True $ zipWith (<=) xs $ tail xs
```

Oh, and **just** for fun:

```
isordered :: [Int] →  Bool
isordered [] = True
isordered (x:xs) = (foldl comp (Just x) xs) /= Nothing
   where comp (Just a) b = if a ≤ b then Just b else Nothing
         comp Nothing _ = Nothing
```